# Is any of the income earned from P2P lending subject to Social Security or Medicare taxes

Tags: united-states, taxes, payroll-taxes, crowdfunding

Income from P2P lending is reported on forms 1099-INT, 1099-B, 1099-MISC and 1099-OID. Are any of these earnings subject to Social Security or Medicare taxes in any way?
I have heard from people they are not, but I can't find anything online to confirm it.

Comment: Strictly speaking, no, but on a technicality. I think you are asking if it would be subject to self-employment tax.

Comment: @chepner Well isn't Self employment tax just Social security and medicare, and that is what I need to know, thx, I'll edit my question to reflect, please answer if you can.

Comment: That's where the money goes; it's just collected differently (paid with your income tax, rather by being withheld/paid by your employer).

Comment: Self-employment tax is, in effect, twice the SS and Medicare tax since you have to pay both the employer's sure as well as the emoloyee's share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked my account and he confirmed that it is investment income and not subject to Social security and medicare taxes.

I guess I should have just done that in the first place instead of waiting a week. Any way I'm sure someone will need this information and god knows it not easy to find. anyway thx to @chepner for helping clarify my question, wish just someone could have answered it so I didn't need to talk to my accountant. 
Cheers!